# How to fix problem with bootstrap 4 grid system?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am facing a problem with the Bootstrap-4 grid system. There are 12 columns, and whenever I use less than 12 columns, the rows are automatically centered. I want left alignment, how can this be fixed?

A snippet of my code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-start con-flex">
    <?php foreach($books as $book):?>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <div id="single-book">
            <div id="book-image">
                <?php print '<img src = "'.strip_tags($book->book_image).'" alt = "">';?>
                <div id="addto-cart"><a href=""><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="book-text">
                <div id="book-name"><?= substr(htmlentities($book->book_name),0,21) ?></div>
                <div id="author">By <i><?= htmlentities($book->author) ?></i></div>
                <div id="price"><?= htmlentities($book->price) ?>.TK</div>
                <div id="book-details">
                    <?php print '<a href = "'.base_url().'users/book_view/'.$book->id.'">View details</a>'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

image of code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pliA.png)

Comment: This situation is clearly covered in the official docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment

Comment: it is not working

Comment: As @IvanS95 mentioned in his answer, the code you have posted already does what you ask ([Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/hqo7JI340d)).  This means that there is something else outside of that code that is influencing the outcome.  Please update your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @IvanS95 now see this. still not working

Comment: @TahmidNishat then you need to provide more context on your code; what you shared should be working just fine; do you have some other CSS on your page?

Comment: Seeing your picture... It seems to me you are including an image inside the column; most likely the image is not using the full width of the column; thus you see "empy space" on the sides

Comment: Yes, I have. Now see the full code. I don't find where the problem actually is...

Comment: Why are you using `col-xs-*`? That's Bootstrap 3 class; no longer in Bootstrap 4... Also what styles does `con-flex` have?

Comment: con-flex is my custom class. con-flex for display flex to maintain the same height of the div.  But it okay when I use 12 columns. I used 100% width for the image.

Comment: Do you have anything else on that class? If not it isn't even necessary as the `.row` class has `display: flex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This problem was for my other base CSS.

Instead of:

```
*{
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For this margin: 0 auto; in my main **style.css** file My bootstrap's grids were not working properly. Now I remove this margin: 0 auto from *.

**Now**

I write

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

**Now my bootstrap grids are working properly**

Answer (score 2):

According to [Bootstrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) that should solve your problem

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class="col-4">
      content here...
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      content here...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is that that's actually the default behavior; columns are aligned to the left; either OPs CSS has something affecting the columns; or maybe he's confusing something

Answer (score 1):

The code you have should be working fine, columns will be aligned left by default; maybe what you are seeing is the result of using `.container` instead of `.container-fluid` which uses the full width of the viewport. It's either this or you might have some custom CSS that's affecting the layout of the columns

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-4 col-md-4 border">content here...</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-4 border">content here...</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-4 col-md-4 border">content here...</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-4 border">content here...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```